# Android: ProgressBar causing crash

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, progress-bar

I will try to explain my problem in a few sentences..
So I am parsing some "web" data in to a list view. But before I fetch all the data I would like to show a progress bar (spinner) where (when the data will be loaded) the list view will later be.
So when the activity start I show the spinner, when the data is fetched I make the spinner disappear.
I think that I am doing some error in my xml file.

If I have like this, the app crash with IOException Broken Pipe:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        <RelativeLayout
        Some stuff   
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
        Some stuff
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ListView
            android:layout_below="@+id/map"
        </ListView>

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_below="@+id/map"
        />

        <include layout="@layout/footer" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

If I have like this the spinner shows up, but then the list view doesn't appear:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    <RelativeLayout
    Some stuff   
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
    Some stuff
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_below="@+id/map"
    />

    <ListView
        android:layout_below="@+id/map"
    </ListView>

    <include layout="@layout/footer" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Console:

```
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:487)
    at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:642)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:347)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:488)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:831)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:799)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.processIncomingJdwpData(DeviceMonitor.java:759)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:648)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$100(DeviceMonitor.java:44)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$3.run(DeviceMonitor.java:576)
```

Comment: did you try restarting your emulator?

Comment: While I way writing the comment I tried again and now works..maybe there was a problem with fetching the data and not with the spinner..
Anyway I have a physic device not an emulator..buuuu thx anyway..

Comment: why don't you have width and height for your views?